# What is difference between @Html.RenderPartial("_Common.cshtml") and @Html.RenderPartial("_Common")

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am facing one problem in `MVC4`. If I am not providing `.cshtml` while calling `RenderPartial` then it is not calling Partial View.

For Example

```
 @Html.RenderPartial("_Common.cshtml") //it is working
 @Html.RenderPartial("_Common") //it is not working
```

**My question is why it is not working?**

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but is there any chance you named it `_Common.cshtml.cshtml`? Another reason can be that the default view locations for the view engine are overridden?

Comment: Use `Partial` for inline Razor syntax, not `RenderPartial`. see below for full details

Comment: @Zabavsky I am also confused its behave. Please check and then reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Zabavsky mentions, you may have an incorrect filename on your partial view (double extension). Just did that yesterday on a project, so easy to do, but **I think you should be using `Partial` and not `RenderPartial`**

Just to clarify which options *should* work:

### 1) The extension of the view file *is* required *if you supply a path*.

### 2) If you do not supply a path, do not supply the extension.

The examples below assume cshtml files.

### Use `RenderPartial` in a code block:

```
// This looks in default view folder, then shared, checking for .aspx, .cshtml etc
Html.RenderPartial("DefinitionDetails"); 

// This looks in specified path and requires the extension
Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Definition/DefinitionDetails.cshtml");
```

### Use `Partial` for inline Razor syntax:

```
// This looks in default view folder, then shared, checking for .aspx, .cshtml etc
@Html.Partial("DefinitionDetails")

// This looks in specified path and requires the extension
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Definition/DefinitionDetails.cshtml")
```

Note: *Apparently `RenderPartial` is slightly faster than `Partial`*, but I also expect fully pathed names will be a faster than letting MVC search for the file.

If you are producing partials in a loop (i.e. from a collection in your view model), it is likely you will need to pass through specific viewmodels:

### e.g.

```
   @foreach (var group in orderedGroups)
   {
       Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/ControllerName/ViewName.cshtml", group);
   }
```

Comment: `Apparently RenderPartial is slightly faster than Partial` - it depends on the amount of HTML returned by the PartialView. `I also expect fully pathed names will be a faster than letting MVC search for the file` - anyway I wouldn't suggest doing so as it's really a view engine's job so let it handle this. Nice answer though.